# Can I apply graph attention networks in datasets with graphs with different sizes?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, graph-neural-network

I would like to test graph attention networks in a problem. However, my dataset has graphs with very different numbers of nodes (ranging from 1 to hundreds). Can I use this kind of network in this dataset? I'm not sure how could I evaluate this.

Best regards.